# Rails 4 production assets returning 502 on AWS ELB and nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

So I have a Rails production app on a couple of AWS EC2 instances, which are being load balanced by an AWS elastic load balancer. The EC2 instances are serving the Rails app through nginx and passenger.

My DNS is pointed at the load balancer, and everything works fine, except that my CSS/JS/assets are not being served. I have `serve_static_files` set to `false` to let nginx take care of it, and I've precompiled my assets with `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile`. When I inspect the assets on chrome, it says there is a `502 Gateway Error`. If I try to hit the assets directly with my web browser, I see nothing, still a `502.`

I've checked my nginx error logs and no 502 errors show up.

I've checked my nginx access logs:

> [ip address redacted] - - [19/Nov/2015:06:04:49 +0000] "GET /assets/application-2386fede65ec2aa6a381b4e3215b6d7278e40c40a9bd5e1c190d0e1d98bafd1d.css HTTP/1.1" 200 12717 "http://admin.somedomain.com/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36"

and it looks fine.

I've checked my Rails logs, and it has nothing asset or 502 related.

I have a separate instance with a DNS record pointed straight to the IP address and not the AWS ELB, which tells me it has something to do with the way the load balancer is trying to return the assets to me. Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 10 hours of trial and error, I have found the culprit in my nginx sites-enabled config file:

```
location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
}
```

This line: `add_header Cache-Control public;` was causing the error. I have no idea what it does, but I'm too tired right now to care.